# PropertyInfo.SetValue(object obj, object val, object[] index) property value doesn't change on changing "object val"

Tags: c#, reflection, propertyinfo, setvalue

I have come across a very weird problem. I am trying to set a property of a particular object assigning it a value of another project via

```
/* PropertyInfo.SetValue(object obj, object val, object[] index) */

propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, val, null)
```

both `obj` and `val` are reference type but the problem is that I want the value of `obj's property` to change when the value of `val` changes. But unfortunately this doesn't happen.
Is there any way to achieve what I want to do.

Regards

Umair

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'this doesn't happen'? I see no obvious problems with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, if you want the property to automagically change whenever you change the contents of the *variable* you pass in, then no, that's not going to happen, you will have to call `SetValue` or similar code again.

On the other hand, if you're not replacing the instance, but modifying the contents of the instance, then that should happen.

In other words, this will work:

```
TestClass val = new TestClass();
val.Name = "Before";
propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, val, null);
val.Name = "After";
```

You're not making a copy of the instance, you're just sharing the reference to it, so the change will be observable both through the variable `val` and the property in question.

However, this will not work:

```
TestClass val = new TestClass();
val.Name = "Before";
propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, val, null);
val = new TestClass();
val.Name = "After";
```

Here you now have two instance, one referenced by the property and one by the variable. There's no way to make the property automagically get that new instance, so you need to find a different way of doing this.